# Using Python visual in Power BI for prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, powerbi, random-forest

I'm using the **Python** visual in **Power BI** to perform prediction of employee turnover using the **random-forest** algorithm and **sklearn**.

This is the [PBIX file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1njzmVk7IC142pfeGFKhnHs1H0XcYP56X/view?usp=sharing) I'm using.

Based on the values in my slicer filters, a prediction will be displayed. This means that the selected values will be my features in this case.

I retrieve the selected values using the **SelectedValue** function by creating parameters for the numerical features and tables manually for the categorical features.

All my data is numerical except 2 columns **Department & Salary Range**

[image]

To go through the creation of the dax measures, I followed **[this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/creating-machine-learning-app-power-bi-pycaret-panama-user-group/)** , I used the Pycaret library and everything for me was success.

Except that I tried now to make sklearn since when I publish to the Power BI Service, Pycaret is sadly not supported.

So I tried the second method to work with sklearn.
The thing is with Pycaret it does One hot encoding automatically for you.
This is the code that I used in for Pycaret (which correctly displays the prediction)

```
from pycaret.classification import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame with the selected feature values
input_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'number_project': [0],  # Placeholder value; will be replaced with the DAX measure value
    'satisfaction_level': [0],  
    'last_evaluation': [0], 
    'Work_accident': [0], 
    'time_spend_company': [0], 
    'salary': [0], 
    'promotion_last_5years': [0], 
    'Department': [0], 
    'bonus': [0], 
    'average_montly_hours': [0], 

})

# Update the DataFrame with DAX measure values
input_data['number_project'] = dataset['number_project']
input_data['satisfaction_level'] = dataset['satisfaction_level']
input_data['last_evaluation'] = dataset['last_evaluation']
input_data['Work_accident'] = dataset['Work_accident']
input_data['time_spend_company'] = dataset['time_spend_company']
input_data['salary'] = dataset['salary']
input_data['promotion_last_5years'] = dataset['promotion_last_5years']
input_data['Department'] = dataset['Department']
input_data['bonus'] = dataset['bonus']
input_data['average_montly_hours'] = dataset['average_montly_hours']

rf = load_model('C:/Users/aziza/Desktop/Sprint PBI/final_rf_powerbi')


# Create prediction with dataset
df1 = predict_model(rf, data = input_data)

# Get the prediction label
predicted_label = df1['Label'].iloc[0]
predicted_score = df1['Score'].iloc[0]
# Convert the prediction score to a percentage rounded to two decimal places
predicted_score_percent = round(predicted_score * 100, 2)

# Convert the prediction to text
if predicted_label == 0:
    prediction_text = f"The employee is likely to stay in \n  the company with a chance of {predicted_score_percent}%."
else:
    prediction_text = f"The employee may leave the company \n with a chance of {predicted_score_percent}%."

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax.axis('off')  # Turn off axis ticks and labels

# Display the prediction as text
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, prediction_text, fontsize=24, ha='center', va='center')

plt.show()
```

The output:

[image]

now I wanted to try the sklearn method, this is what I gotten to so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'number_project': [0],  # Placeholder value; will be replaced 
    'satisfaction_level': [0],  
    'last_evaluation': [0], 
    'Work_accident': [0], 
    'time_spend_company': [0], 
    'salary': [0], 
    'promotion_last_5years': [0], 
    'Department': [0],  
    'bonus': [0], 
    'average_monthly_hours': [0], 
})

# Update the DataFrame with the actual input values from Power BI slicers
input_data['number_project'] = dataset['number_project'] 
input_data['satisfaction_level'] = dataset['satisfaction_level'] 
input_data['last_evaluation'] = dataset['last_evaluation'] 
input_data['Work_accident'] = dataset['Work_accident']
input_data['time_spend_company'] = dataset['time_spend_company'] 


# Perform one-hot encoding using pd.get_dummies for 'salary' and 'Department' columns
input_data = pd.get_dummies(input_data, columns=['salary', 'Department'], drop_first=True)

input_data['promotion_last_5years'] = dataset['promotion_last_5years']  
input_data['bonus'] = dataset['bonus']
input_data['average_montly_hours'] = dataset['average_montly_hours'] 


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Load the trained model (assumed to be RandomForestClassifier)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=8, max_features=0.75, n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(dataset.drop('left', axis=1), dataset['left'])  # Assuming 'left' is the target variable

# Make predictions with the input data
predicted_label = rf.predict(input_data)[0]
predicted_score = rf.predict_proba(input_data)[0][1]  # Probability of the positive class

# Convert the prediction score to a percentage rounded to two decimal places
predicted_score_percent = round(predicted_score * 100, 2)

# Convert the prediction to text
if predicted_label == 0:
    prediction_text = f"The employee is likely to stay in \n the company with a chance of {predicted_score_percent}%."
else:
    prediction_text = f"The employee may leave the company \n with a chance of {predicted_score_percent}%."

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax.axis('off')  # Turn off axis ticks and labels

# Display the prediction as text
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, prediction_text, fontsize=24, ha='center', va='center')

plt.show()
```

THis is the current output:

[image]
[image]

I tried everything with HotOneEncoding , LabelEncoding, Mapping and nothing of these worked. Encoding may not seem to work before passing to the model.